# Date range filter in data tables isn't working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, date, datatables

I wrote a data table with a date range filter. In `Minimum Date:` and `Maximum Date:`, I'm using fixed values `01/01/2010` and `01/01/2012` respectively. When page loads, dates falling under given date range should load automatically. But it isn't happening even though there are some dates which are clearly out of the given range.
[Maybe this JSFiddle link can explain it better.](https://jsfiddle.net/4w1552jp/1/)
My jQuery code is:

```
/*$('#data').dataTable();*/
$(function() {
  $('#minDate').datepicker();
  $('#maxDate').datepicker();
});
// Function for converting a mm/dd/yyyy date value into a numeric string for comparison (example 08/12/2010 becomes 20100812
function parseDateValue(rawDate) {
  var dateArray = rawDate.split("/");
  var parsedDate = dateArray[2] + dateArray[0] + dateArray[1];
  return parsedDate;
}
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    var iFini = parseDateValue(document.getElementById('minDate').value);
    var iFfin = parseDateValue(document.getElementById('maxDate').value);
    var evalDate = parseDateValue(aData[4]);

    if (evalDate >= iFini && evalDate <= iFfin) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }
);
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#data').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copyHtml5',
      'excelHtml5',
      'csvHtml5',
      'pdfHtml5'
    ]
  });

  // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
  $('#minDate, #maxDate').keyup(function() {
    table.draw();
  });
});
```

How can I make data tables filter the data based on fixed values when page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing apples with oranges here. Your dates are in different formats with your inputs being `DD/MM/YYYY` and your table rows being `YYYY/MM/DD`, no wonder things were going wrong. I'd use another library, [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), and use this code:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    var iFini = ~~moment($('#minDate').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY").format("X");
    var iFfin = ~~moment($('#maxDate').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY").format("X");
    var evalDate = ~~moment(aData[4], "YYYY/MM/DD").format("X");
    if (evalDate >= iFini && evalDate <= iFfin) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cool, mine was a bad mixture :D

Comment: It's always useful to check dates. Being in the UK means we have to cope with the USA date format all the time - this is why `momentjs` rocks TBH - why bother with having to cope with odd JS date parsing (months being a zero-based array for instance) when someone has gone to all the effort of creating `momentjs`? ;-) Stand on the shoulders of giants! You're also using a lot of Vanilla Javascript `document.getElementById('minDate').value` when you can use jQuery (You need it in order for DataTables to run after all).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that your using the function **parseDateValue** to convert the dates in your filters and also the dates in your table before comparing them, but, the date format in your table rows is different from the date format in your filters, so you will get:

> min date = 01/01/2010  => 20100101
>
> max date = 01/01/2012  => 20120101

and for example in your first row you have

> date = 2011/04/25  => 25201104

So when you compare, it won't be good.

But if you change the date format in your rows (for example `25/04/2011`), it will works fine.

Comment: I removed `parseDateValue` as you suggested. However table is still empty... Data which falls under specified range should be shown when page loads

Comment: Changing `parseDateValue` won't work unless you implement a different function for returning the number for the inputs and the rows. I'd remove the function and parse it differently. Check my answer.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni I didn't say to remove the parseDateValue, I said, you can't use it with two differents formats, so I suggested to change the date format in your table rows (or you can use two differents date parsing functions, one for the filter inputs and one for the rows date)

Comment: Hey sorry @b-assam, the comment was directed at AjayKulkarni rather than you. I was expanding upon you answer, sorry for the confusion :-)

Comment: @annoyingmouse no pbl :) I was also answering Ajay comment ( I don't know how he did understand that I suggested to remove parseDateValue :D ), I expained to him the pbl, but you made his life easier by giving him the full answer ;)